# Select only first element using :contains or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, contains

I have an svg map that has ids on the "g" attr and a list of products with classes on each.  When clicking a section on the map, products with that section class matching the id on the "g" element are filtered.

Here is my code.

```
<g id="225" class="available">
      <polygon points=" 1302.4 446.2 1238.2 469.4 1310 530.1 1375.1 505.3 " class="i"></polygon>
    </g>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('g g').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $svgelement = $(this);
        var id = $svgelement.attr('id');
        var $item = $('.Ticket');
        var $itemChild = $('div.product:first-child:contains('+id+')');

        $item.filter(function(e){

            if($(this).find($itemChild).length > 0){
                $(this).slideDown('fast');
            } else {
                $(this).slideUp('fast');
            }

        });
    });
});

<div class="Ticket">
<div class="first post-4490 product type-product status-publish product_cat-kentucky-derby-grandstand-tickets product_cat-kentucky-derby-tickets product_tag-section-225 pa_row-f taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-kentucky-derby-grandstand-tickets product-cat-kentucky-derby-tickets product-tag-section-225 instock">

    <div class="ticketSection col">
    <!--<a href="https://www.derbydeals.com/ticket/derby-section-225-row-f/">-->
<span class="Section">
    225<br>     <!--</a>-->
</span>

</div>

<div class="ticketRow col">
    <span class="rowNum">
    F<br>   </span>
</div>

<!--<div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="ticketQty col">
    <span class="Qty">10</span>
</div>-->

<div class="ticketPrice Price col"><span style="display: none;"> data-value="475"&gt;</span>


    <span class="price"><span class="amount">$475.00</span></span>

<!--<a href="https://www.derbydeals.com/ticket/derby-section-225-row-f/" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
View Details
</a>-->
</div>
<div class="orderOpen col">
    <!--<span class="qtyMsg">How many tickets?</span>-->



    <form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="quantity_select" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"><select name="quantity" title="Qty" class="qty"><option value="2">2</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="6">6</option></select></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="4490">

        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>

            </form>


    <div class="detailsLink">
<a href="https://www.derbydeals.com/ticket/derby-section-225-row-f/" class="alt">View Seating Details</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This works fine except it's looking for at the siblings too; a problem with using :contains probably.

For example, clicking on section 225 on the map filters all the products correctly with section 225 in the class name, but it also shows products that have 225 in the price.  So it will show section 322 because the price is 1,225.

I've tried using filter as a function, next, :first-child, closest, first and different combinations of :contains but nothing works.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Update!

Here is a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k9uvqhxb/1/

Comment: I am not really sure i understand your problem, but following your title, i´d say     var $itemChild = $('div.product:first-child:contains('+id+')')[0];

Comment: That doesn't work so I've added the code that jquery is looking at for more context.  The problem is that it's not just looking at the div after .Ticket but using first-child doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for that?

Comment: Now i understand your problem a bit better. I would change your code, add classes or data-attributes to the product container. And then changing $('div.product:first-child:contains('+id+')'); to $('.CLASSNAME');

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to the OP

Comment: @StefanVilbrandt - what if I don't have access to that code and I have to work with only the script?

Comment: Err, let my think about it. I will answer later again.

Comment: I added a class to the .Ticket div that's the slug of the product term, so g id is 225 and .Ticket as another class called 225

Answer (score 0):

I added a class to the .Ticket div that's the slug of the product term, so g id is 225 and .Ticket has another class called 225 or whatever the slug is

Now I'm simply using hasClass like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('g g').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $svgelement = $(this);
        var id = $svgelement.attr('id');
        var $item = $('.Ticket');

        $item.each(function(e){

            if($(this).hasClass(id)){
                $(this).slideDown('fast');
            } else {
                $(this).slideUp('fast');
            }

        return;

        });
    });
});
```

which works as intended